# Subfiles is not ignoring \end{document}

Tags: subfiles

As far as I understand the subfiles for use in the `subfiles` package should all end with `\end{document}`, so that they can be built independently. However, I'm finding that, in order for each of my subfiles to be included in the output of my `main.tex` file, I need to delete the `\end{document}` line. I'm using **TeXstudio**.

My main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \subfile{title}
    \subfile{introduction}
\end{document}
```

If the subfiles look like this:

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    title content OR introduction content
\end{document}
```

then I get only the content of the first subfile (`title.tex`) in `main.pdf`, even if the content is as simple as just the word 'content'. If they look like this instead:

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    content
```

then I get the content of both.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My guess is that the cause of your problem is a version mismatch: a new `subfiles` package (v2.2) with an old LaTeX (older than Oct 2020), or the other way around.  You find the version numbers in the log file. I see there `preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.4.16` and `subfiles 2020/11/14 v2.2`.

Comment: Thank you! I had a look and my pdflatex version is 2019.1.4, which would presumably be the problem.

Comment: After fully updating MiKTeX it's all working now, so it definitely was a version mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

The observed behavior may arise from a version mismatch: a new subfiles package (v2.2) with an old LaTeX (older than Oct 2020), or the other way around. You find the version numbers in the log file. I see there `preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.4.16` and `subfiles 2020/11/14 v2.2`.

Best use the package manager of your distribution to update all formats and packages.